# LDAP not authenticating in Joomla 4 Alpha 12

Tags: symfony, joomla, ldap, joomla-extensions

I'm trying to set LDAP with Joomla 4, but it's giving ConnectionException when binding the user.
I copied exactly the same settings from Joomla 3.9, still not work.

I know that in version 4, the LDAP authentication moved to Symfony, but the settings parameters are the same as early versions.

Is there's any other configuration that I need to look it at?

```
[host] => xxxxx
[port] => 389
[use_ldapV3] => 1
[negotiate_tls] => 0
[ignore_reqcert_tls] => 1
[no_referrals] => 0
[auth_method] => bind
[base_dn] => dc=xxxx,dc=xxx,dc=xx
[search_string] => 
[users_dn] => uid=[username],ou=users,dc=xxxxx,dc=xxx,dc=xx
[ldap_fullname] => displayName
[ldap_email] => mail
[ldap_uid] => uid
[ldap_debug] => 1
```

Comment: Yes, where is your bind dn ?

Comment: @EricLavault You mean my username? There's no bind dn on plugin configuration.